# Actual data from KFold split indices

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

Suppose I have the following data:

```
y = np.ones(10)
y[-5:] = 0
X = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(10,20, size=(10)),
                  'b':np.random.randint(80,90, size=(10))})
X    
    a   b
0   11  82
1   19  82
2   15  80
3   15  86
4   14  82
5   18  87
6   13  83
7   12  83
8   10  82
9   18  87
```

Splitting it to 5-fold gives the following indices:

```
kf =  KFold()
data = list(kf.split(X,y))
data
[(array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1])),
 (array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([2, 3])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([4, 5])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]), array([6, 7])),
 (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([8, 9]))]
```

But I want to further prepare `data`  such that it is organise to contain the actual values in the format:

```
data =
   [(train1,trainlabel1,test1,testlabel1),
    (train2,trainlabel2,test2,testlabel2),
     ..,
    (train5,trainlabel5,test5,testlabel5)]
```

Expected Output (from the given MWE):

```
[array([
        (array([[15,80],[15,86],[14,82],[18,87],[13,83],[12,83],[10,82],[18,87]]), array([[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0])]), #fold1 train/label
        (array([[11,82],[19,82]]), array([[1],[1]])),  #fold1 test/label

        (array([[11,82],[19,82],[14,82],[18,87],[13,83],[12,83],[10,82],[18,87]]),array([[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]])), #fold2 train/label
        (array([[15,80],[15,86]]),array([[1],[1]])) #fold2 test/label

        ....
])]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you understand, `KFold().split(data)` returns the selected indices by fold.
To select Pandas.DataFrame rows with indices list, the easiest way is the [loc method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```
for train_idx, test_idx in KFold(n_splits=2).split(X):
   x_train = X.loc[train_idx]
   x_test = X.loc[test_idx]

   y_train = y.loc[train_idx]
   y_test = y.loc[test_idx]
```

You can then add you subset dataframes to lists

Comment: This gives the following error: ``AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'loc'``

Comment: to use Pandas.DataFrame.loc, it needs to be a DataFrame indeed. Try to  convert it.. `pd.DataFrame(y)`